# how to integrate torch into a docker image while keeping image size reasonable?

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

So I've a Flask web app that will be exposing some deep learning models.

I built the image and everything works fine.

the problem is the size of this image is 5.58GB! which is a bit ridiculous.

I have some deep learning models that are copied during the build, I thought they might be the culprit but their size combined does not exceed `300MB` so that's definately not it.

upon checking the history and the size of each layer I discovered this:

- `RUN /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt` is taking up **771MB**.
- `RUN /bin/sh -c pip install torch==1.10.2` is taking up **2.8GB**!
- `RUN /bin/sh -c apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6` is taking up **400MB**.

so how do I incorporate these libraries while keeping image size reasonable? is it ok to have images of these size when deploying ml models in python?

below is the `root directory`:

[image]

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7.13
WORKDIR /app 
COPY ["rdm.pt", "autosort_model.pt", "rotated_model.pt", "yolov5x6.pt", "/app/"]
RUN pip install torch==1.10.2
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
COPY . /app
CMD python ./app.py
```

`.dockerignore`:

```
Dockerfile
README.md
__pycache__
```

Comment: While I think your question is fairly clear without it, I can't copy and run the PNG-format Dockerfile.  You should almost never include screen shots of your source files in SO questions; include the text of the file in a code block instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default torch will package CUDA packages and stuff. Add `--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu` and `--no-cache-dir` to pip install command if you do not require CUDA.

`RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`

Also it's good practice to remove the apt list cache:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    ffmpeg \
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```